# OAuth2 with no UI?

Tags: box-api

I'm in the middle of developing an application that integrates Box with an identity management environment for the purposes of SSO and user lifecycle management. Basically, our users use SAML to sign into their Box accounts, and then the status of their Box accounts is managed based on the status of their corporate accounts - if we terminate a user, the user's Box account needs to get disabled. This is one of many use cases that were in progress before the OAuth2 change.

Prior to the OAuth2 change, I was able to authenticate my enterprise admin account with the api_key and auth_token. This worked very well.

Now, with OAuth2, I'm not sure how to proceed. There is no UI for this at all, and I have no place to handle a redirect for the authorization token. Moreover, this is a nightly process that runs using the enterprise admin account, so I would have to get a new refresh token and bearer token every time this runs.

This doesn't make a lot of sense for my use case. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

I am busy writing the same code with the same frustration as you have.  However the refresh token does live for 14 days and what I plan to do is store the returned values encrypted in the registry.  Each run my first action is to refresh the bearer key.

There however is no current timeline on the phasing out of the V1 Auth method and since some of the Enterprise stuff is yet to be ported to API V2 I suspect that if enough Enterprises push the BOX API team for a solution on this I am sure they will listen.

If I am honest I prefer the OAuth2 solution as it stops the key to your whole Enterprise data been sent in clear text across the internet as a URL param in API V1 and if someone did manage to break the SSL then only get a access token that is worth 60 mins max.

Not sure what language your writing the routines in but I am working with the API V2 SDK written by John Hoerr on GitHub and apart from a few little issues that he has fixed straight away from a .Net perspective it makes hitting the API a much more pleasant experience with all the de\serialisation handled by the SDK.

Comment: I ended up just throwing together a very small JSP and servlet so that I could bootstrap the tokens, then I'm going to save the tokens and just refresh them. The stuff I'm writing is using an EAI tool that uses java and javascript to transform data, so I've just scripted the refresh piece of it.